# Issue with Date Range when adding Events Web Part?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, office-365, events

I am new to Sharepoint and am putting together a site for our internal users. I am wanting to add an events web part that will show upcoming events and internal birthdays. When adding this i am able to pull info into the web part. The only issue i run into is the "Date Range" field.

Is there something special i am needing to do to get this corrected? i am looking to make it the upcoming week but it is still showing all birthdays from year to date.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that need to do to get the upcoming event except selecting “All upcoming events” under “Date range” field in Events Web Part in SharePoint Online modern page.

If you can get the correct event when you select other options in “Date range” field?

Try to delete the web part and insert a new one and check again. Or select other events list to narrow down the issue.